# Move the root from one subvolume to another in BTRFS

Tags: grub2, btrfs

I want to install Ubuntu in the BTRFS `@root` subvolume, but the Ubuntu installer does not allow changing the default subvolumes and installs in `@` and `@home`.

I'm trying to create a `@root` subvolume after installation, but I have a problem. I need to edit `fstab` and GRUB. GRUB needs to know where to find the new root. I've read that the community edits `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` but some people say it's unsafe because `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` will be overwritten on the next kernel update or when you run `update-grub`.

How can I move the root from one subvolume to another?

Comment: Do you want to keep separate `@home`? In this case it is much easier.

Comment: @Pilot6 It's not matter. The main goal move root to new subvolume `@root`. In general I think about structure `@root`, `@home`, `@swap`.

Comment: So the only point is to change the name. You can simply rename the subvolume and update-grub as mentioned in my answer. No need to copy or move anything. But it makes no sense. You'll have `/home` at `@home`, `/swap` at `@swap` and `/` at `@root`. it makes no sense and is confusing, because there is `/root` too.

Comment: @Pilot6 Not really. I will have [Flat Layout](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/SysadminGuide#Flat:~:text=in%20the%20filesystem.-,Layout,-There%20are%20several). But it like rename. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not very complicated if you know what you are doing.

1. Boot from a LiveUSB.
2. Mount the disk to `/mnt` and create `@root` subvolume.
3. Copy using `cp -a` everything from `@` and `@home` to `@root`. You can use `mv`, but it is safer to keep the old subvolumes before all settles.
4. Update `/etc/fstab` with `subvol=@root` option. Don't forget to remove the `/home` mount if you don't want a separate `/home`. (Why?)
5. Mount the disk to e.g. `/mnt` with `-O subvol=@root`. Also run

   ```
    sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
    sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
    sudo mount --bind /sys  /mnt/sys
   ```
6. Chroot to `/mnt` and update grub.

Comment: Do you want to say I don't need edit GRUB file? Only edit `fstab` and use `update-grub` ?

Comment: `update-grub` will create a correct file.